# what is the difference between index.js vs page.js in next.js?

Tags: javascript, next.js

1. https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

I was going through this next.js docs.

- Here it says index.js acts as root of the directory. So If I enter `/blog` in the URL it takes me to `pages/blog/index.js` file.

Now my question is I have `pages/blog/subcomponent.js` I don't want users to access `/blog/subcomponent` because it is a subcomponent. How can I do that?

2. https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/pages-and-layouts

Now I saw another documentation from next.js that we can use `page.js` instead of `index.js` and only `page.js` becomes publicly accessible.

- so does that mean the other files cannot be accessible if it is not `page.js`?

I'm really confused. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

There are two types of routing in Nextjs:

1. Pages router
2. App router

### Pages router (The first link you shared)

It enforces you to use **index.tsx** if you have the page component in a folder of pages directory, and if you don't want to use a folder, you can just directly create a file with page name in your pages directory. Such as:

pages/blog.js → /blog    (wihtout folder)

pages/blog/index.js → /blog   (within a folder)

### App router (The second link you shared)

It enforces you to use **pages.tsx** if you have the page component in a folder of app directory, and if you don't want to use a folder, you can just directly create a file with page name in your app directory. Such as:

app/blog.js → /blog    (wihtout folder)

app/blog/pages.js → /blog   (within a folder)

As for other files in the folder, they won't be accessible as long as you have pages.tsx or index.tsx in your folder. But it is not a good practice to place components in pages or app folder. You should only place the page main component in these directory.